# Linq 2 Sql insert without relationship

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, orm

I have 2 tables. eg: One of them is to store Users and the other is to store Orders. Orders table containing UserId as a foreign key. I'm using Linq 2 Sql for data access operations. I want to insert an Order without inserting a User row if the user already exists in the database.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Edit: Here is the code I have problems with:

```
try
{
    context.SocialEntities.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Contains("UserUniqueness"))
    {                     
        User user = context.Users.Where(u => u.SourceUserID == entity.User.SourceUserID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.SocialEntities.Add(entity);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

UserUniqueness is a unique key constraint defined in the User table for a column named SocialSourceId. And it is not primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the new order to the existing user's `Orders` collection.

**UPDATE:**
I suggest, you do the check for the user before trying to insert it. I guess, that the user you tried to add somehow still is in your context and gets submitted again the next time you call `SubmitChanges`.

Comment: It still says: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UserUniqueness'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.User'. User table has a unique key constraint

Comment: What are you doing with the user? Please edit your question and provide some code.

Comment: This doesn't help any further, sorry. I suggest, you do the check for the user before trying to insert it. I guess, that the user you tried to add somehow still is in your context and gets submitted again the next time you call `SubmitChanges`.

Comment: That was the problem! You are right! Thanks a lot!. I'll accept your answer, you may want to update it!